# Static mechanics: I get two different forces in an equilibrium system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, statics

The problem comes from *"Engineering Mechanics Statics Dynamics"* by Russell Charles(newest edition), on page  97, f3-4. You can see it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nw7iN4BnU44

The $x $ axis is parallel to the surface of where the box lies. The $y $ axis is in the same direction as the normal force.

Gravitational force on the block: $W$

The normal Force: $F_n$

The force that pushes the box in the $x-$axis direction: $F_d$

The force on the box from the spring: $F_s$

Since there is $45$ degree angle between the surface and a horizontal line we have,
$F_d=W \mathrm{cos} \ 45$ and $F_n=W\mathrm{sin} \ 45$.

Since $\sqrt{0,4^2+0,3^2}=0,5$ we have  $\frac{F_s}{5}=\frac{F_{s_x}}{4}$ and $\frac{F_s}{5}=\frac{F_{s_y}}{3}$.

Since the system is in equilibrium we have that $F_{s_x}=F_d=W\mathrm{cos} \  45$ and $F_{s_y}=F_n=W\mathrm{sin} \ 45$, so we get $F_s=\frac{5W \mathrm{cos} \ 45}{4}$ and $F_s=\frac{5W\mathrm{sin} \ 45}{3}$ which isn't right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is arising because you have calculated the normal force incorrectly.

As the block is in equilibrium, the forces have to be balanced in both $x$ and  $y$ directions. For the $x$ direction, your force balance equation is correct $(F_{s_x}=W\cos 45)$. For the $y$ direction though, the force balance equation is
\begin{equation}
F_{s_y} + F_n = W \sin 45
\end{equation}

The normal force does not just counteract the weight of the body on the surface. It balances out the *net normal force* that the surface experiences.